# Application insights, and it's maximum storage ability on telemetry

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I have a middleware telemetry handler, that has a method that awaits the execution of a request, and then tries to store some key data values from the response body into custom dimensions fields in application insights, so I can use graphana and potentially other 3rd party products to analyse my reponses.

```
public class ResponseBodyHandler : IResponseBodyHandler
{
    private readonly ITelemetryPropertyHandler _telemetryPropertyHandler = new TelemetryPropertyHandler();
    
    public void TransformResponseBodyDataToTelemetryData(RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, string responseBody)
    {
        SuccessResponse<List<Booking>> result = null;
        try
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuccessResponse<List<Booking>>>(responseBody);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("Telemetry response handler, failure to deserialize response body: " + e.Message);
            return;
        }

        _telemetryPropertyHandler.CreateTelemetryProperties(requestTelemetry, result);
    }
}

public class TelemetryPropertyHandler : ITelemetryPropertyHandler
    {
        private readonly ILabelHandler _labelHandler = new LabelHandler();
        public void CreateTelemetryProperties(RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, SuccessResponse<List<Booking>> result)
        {
            Header bookingHeader = result?.SuccessObject?.FirstOrDefault()?.BookingHeader;
            requestTelemetry?.Properties.Add("ResponseClientId", "" + bookingHeader?.ConsigneeNumber);
            
            Line line = bookingHeader?.Lines.FirstOrDefault();
            requestTelemetry?.Properties.Add("ResponseProductId", "" + line?.PurchaseProductID);
            requestTelemetry?.Properties.Add("ResponseCarrierId", "" + line?.SubCarrierID);

            _labelHandler.HandleLabel(requestTelemetry, bookingHeader);
            
            requestTelemetry?.Properties.Add("ResponseBody", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
        }
    }
```

Now, inside: _labelHandler.HandleLabel(requestTelemetry, bookingHeader);
It extracts an Image that is base64 encoded, chunks up the string in sizes of 8192 characters, and adds them to the Properties as: Image index 0 .. N (N being the total chunks)

I can debug and verify that the code works.
However, on application insights, the entire "request" entry, is missing, not just the custom dimensions.
I am assuming that this is due to a maximum size constraint, and I am likely trying to add more data than is "allowed", however, I can't for the life of me, find the documentation that enforces this restriction.

Can someone tell what rule I am breaking? so I can either truncate the image out, if it isn't possible to store that much data? Or if there is something else I am doing wrong?

I have validated, that my code works fine, as long as I truncate the data into a single Property, that of course only partially stores the Image. (Making said "feature" useless)

```
public class LabelHandler : ILabelHandler
{
    private readonly IBase64Splitter _base64Splitter = new Base64Splitter();
    
    public void HandleLabel(RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, Header bookingHeader)
    {
        Label label = bookingHeader?.Labels.FirstOrDefault();
        IEnumerable<List<char>> splitBase64String = _base64Splitter.SplitList(label?.Base64.ToList());

        if (splitBase64String != null)
        {
            bool imageHandlingWorked = true;
            try
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (List<char> chunkOfImageString in splitBase64String)
                {
                    string dictionaryKey = $"Image index {index}";
                    string chunkData = new string(chunkOfImageString.ToArray());
                    requestTelemetry?.Properties.Add(dictionaryKey, chunkData);
                    index++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                imageHandlingWorked = false;
                Log.Error("Error trying to store label in chunks: " + e.Message);
            }
            
            if (imageHandlingWorked && label != null)
            {
                label.Base64 = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is responsible for adding the chunks to a requestTelemetry Property field

```
public class Base64Splitter : IBase64Splitter
    {
        private const int ChunkSize = 8192;

        public IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitList<T>(List<T> originalList)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < originalList.Count; i += ChunkSize)
                yield return originalList.GetRange(i, Math.Min(ChunkSize, originalList.Count - i));
        }
    }
```

This is the specific method for creating a char list chunk of characters, that correspond to the application insights maximum size pr custom dimension field.

Here is an image of the truncated field being added, if I just limit myself to a single property, but truncate the base64 encoded value.

[image: Image of field being present (truncated)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'm from Application Insights team]

You can find field limits documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-request-telemetry

On ingestion side there is a limit of 64 * 1024 bytes for overall JSON payload (need to add it to documentation).

You're facing something different though - that custom dimensions are removed completely. Maybe SDK detects that 64kb is exceeded and "mitigates" it this way. Can you try to limit it to a little bit less than 64kb?

Comment: I have amended my question, there is actually no request at all stored, I mistook a trace for a request, I know, sloppy work. I apologies. 

I am currently trying to truncate the data when it exceeds 64kb. 

My alternative, is to store the image else where, like on another server or something, splitting the image up like this also feels super "dirty", like I am trying to circumvent a restriction, I shouldn't be trying to circumvent. 

I just wish it was easier to store big blobs of data.

I mean, we are paying for the storage space, there is a business case here :D

Comment: My PO has approved that i simply remove the image. As the partial storage is obviously not relevant. We will have to store the image elsewhere, or just not store it ever. 
(Not storing it has been accepted for now, if it turns out we need to produce it later, we will setup a separate storage, like a fileserver, and then store the URL for the image in the requestTelemetry.

Comment: I have also verified, like you said, that the limit is 64kb. That is the cut off point.
Thank you for your help, it mattered greatly to my PO, that I got a response from someone in the application insights team! So thank you so much!

Comment: Great that it helped! Yes, uploading an image to a dedicated service (or to Azure Storage) and having a link to it in custom dimension is the correct strategy.